# Multilple listviews in one single activity

Tags: android

I want to have more than one dynamic listview with title in one signle activity.each list item has the image and it's name.i have to do like below image.Please suggest any solution.
[image]
Thanks,

Comment: use list view inside an expandable list view ..

Answer (score 1):

you have two options:

i) either partition screen in two parts using weight attribute and use different listviews.

or

ii) you can take a look at good tutorial [here](http://umakantpatil.com/posts/android-listview-with-separate-headers-and-images-loading-from-remote-server) for an idea.

one more concept if you find easy is using [MergeAdapter](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge)

Comment: Thanks for your reply I think MergeAdapter used  some libs which i can not be used.do u have any other demo example for the same.